# Open two incognito sessions in protractor using different user-data-dir paths

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver

So I have some protractor tests and I have the following problems.
Some of the tests must run on incognito but with cookies allowed. Because I couldn't find something to start the incognito page with cookies allowed I used the user-data-dir="path" in my chrome options. So this is ok for now.
But then I get another problem. When I need to run a test that opens two chrome sessions I get the following error for the second session: 
 *"WebDriverError: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir".*
Without that user data directory I cannot run the other tests because I need to run them on incognito with cookies allowed.
Any ideas?

Comment: second session - another browser instance, or another tab within the same browser?

Comment: Another browser instance.